# How do I distinguish between for consumeable products and for products that aren't consumed?

Tags: in-app-billing, billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I used 'com.android.billingclient: billing: 2.0.3'.

How do I distinguish between for consumable products and for products that aren't consumed?

Consumables are approved for purchase with `consumeAsync()` and non-consumable products are approved for purchase with `acknowledgePurchase()`.

**It seems like consumable products and non-consumable products are classified through whether consumeAsync() is called or not.**

**1. Are there other methods of classification?**

(https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#acknowledge/)

**2. acknowledgePurchase () is directed to apis for non-consumable products. Shouldn't it be used for consumable products?**

I can add a developer paylaod this way:

For consumable products, consumeAsync() takes a ConsumeParams object that includes a developer payload field, as shown in the following example:

```
BillingClient client = ...
ConsumeResponseListener listener = ...

ConsumeParams consumeParams =
    ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
        .setPurchaseToken(/* token */)
        .setDeveloperPayload(/* payload */)
        .build();

client.consumeAsync(consumeParams, listener);
```

For products that aren't consumed, acknowledgePurchase() takes an AcknowledgePurchaseParams object that includes a developer payload field, as shown in the following example:

```
BillingClient client = ...
AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener listener = ...

AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
    AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
        .setPurchaseToken(/* token */)
        .setDeveloperPayload(/* payload */)
        .build();

client.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, listener);
```

(https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#attach_a_developer_payload)

**3. Do you plan to add management type for consumable and non-consumable products in the future?**

**4. Could the call be restricted for mistyped functions?**

Answer (score 2):

Google Play doesn't have the knowledge of consumable SKUs vs non-consumable SKUs. Only developers have this knowledge.

If you would like users to repeated purchase one SKU (like coins, gems), then you can call consumeAsync() to remove it from user's library. Google Play won't allow users to repurchase a SKU if it is already in his library. Therefore, you have to consume it (remove it from his library).

For some other SKU, such as subscription or ads free, premium content unlock, limited item, if you want users only buy once then don't consume it. Instead, use acknowledgePurchase API. Google Play introduced this as a contract to make sure that you have granted the products to users.

Therefore, I would say keep a catalog of consumable, non-consumable SKUs on your side. And based on the type, call the correct Google's API.

Comment: Your answer is very unclear and contradicts itself in many sentences

Answer (score 1):

For what I understand so far,

non-consumable product call acknowledgePurchase() is to set the purchase record to acknowledged in Google side, so when u trying to trigger queryPurchase(), it will show the product is purchased with acknowledged (parse the json data to view the data)

consumable product call consumeAsync() is to remove the data in Google side. So when trigger queryPurchase() should be no record for that.

Why consumable product can purchase again?
Because the record ady removed from the record. When trigger purchase again will not return error code 7 (BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED)

both consumeAsync() and acknowledgePurchase() also will set the payment to done. If didn't trigger anyone of them, then it will auto refund after 3 days. Both of the action also work as acknowledge the payment.

So for your question

**1. Are there other methods of classification?**

Those acknowledged one should be non-consumable product, since consumable product record should be removed after success record to our side. Or if want to classify, maybe can set developer payload for the acknowledgement(can't changed after set)

**2. acknowledgePurchase () is directed to apis for non-consumable products. Shouldn't it be used for consumable products?**

no, use it separately based on your requirement

The answer maybe incorrect. Just some sharing about it.

welcome to answer my question also related to this, acknowledgement perform at server side

[Server side can do something similar to mobile side comsumeAsync() in Google Billing Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58130582/server-side-can-do-something-similar-to-mobile-side-comsumeasync-in-google-bil)