# Server side can do something similar to mobile side comsumeAsync() in Google Billing Library?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

For consumable products, use `consumeAsync()`, found in the client API.

For products that aren't consumed, use `acknowledgePurchase()`, found in the client API.

A new acknowledge() method is also available in the server API.

---

After purchase the consumable product, is there any way can acknowledge the purchase in our backend side to allow second purchase?

[Billing library overview](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#acknowledge)
[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcBH0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar url which is used for server-side verification of an in-app purchase to acknowledge an in-app purchase. Its a POST method instead of a GET we use for verification. And you need to add acknowledge at the end.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/purchases/products/productId/tokens/token:acknowledge
```

This might be helpful. https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/acknowledge

Comment: But this acknowledgement API is work same as consumeAsync()?
Bec for mobile side current is only call acknowledgement API, it only set isAcknowledgement to true. So when we query out purchase history, the record still thr, so second purchase will not allow to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/341
Answer provided by Google developer